# PyCharm E126 over-indented for hanging indent

Tags: pycharm

While using PyCharm, I'm getting `E126 continuation line over-indented for hanging indent` errors on the following code:

```
bool_one = True
bool_two = False
ex_var: bool = (
        is_even(5) and
        bool_one and
        bool_two
)
```

I originally had these three boolean statements all on one line, but hit enter to put them on separate lines to make it easier to read. PyCharm handled the indent for me.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out PyCharm is configured (by default?) to use 8 spaces for 'continuation indent'. I changed this to 4, and now no longer receive the E126 error!

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a multi-line comment was the cause of this same problem for me. I don't understand why, as I haven't experienced this with other python files that contained multi-line comments before today. Alas, luckily, I am able to do without the comment in this case. FWIW, the error happens for me as a multi-line comment and as a multi-line string variable.